# How to compare entry values in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to compare the user defined value(us_level) to the value generated by tkinter(self.level), here is my code

```
class Prime(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self,hello):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,hello)

    self.level=tk.IntVar()
    self.i=tk.IntVar()
    self.us_level=tk.IntVar()

    tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.level).pack()
    tk.Label(self, text="this is the current oil level").pack()
    E1=tk.Entry(self,textvar=self.us_level)
    E1.pack()
    self.us_level=E1.get()
def specify_level(self):
    if self.level.get()>=self.us_level.get():
            emergency_lock()
    else:
            print("continue")
```

it shows me the error  in specify_level
    if self.level>=self.us_level:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'IntVar' and 'str'
*sorry if i am not very clear but its my first time here

Comment: You overwrote the IntVar named `self.us_level` at the end of `.__init__()`, with the contents of the Entry at that moment in time.  (Which is nothing, since that moment in time was immediately after creating the Entry, before the user could possibly type anything into it).  You have no further reference to the IntVar, and kept no reference to the Entry, so you simply cannot do anything further with it.

Comment: So what do I do? Not declare it as an intvar? But then the default value becomes string... What can I do then?